# jquery .val() not working on 'input' event?

Tags: jquery

i have the following piece of code:

```
  var search_input = $('#dynatable-search-');
  search_input.on('input', function() {
    console.log('input change detected', search_input.val(), 'and', this.value);
    dynatable.data('dynatable').queries.runSearch(search_input.val());
  });
```

I would like the search_input to fire runSearch whenever the text inside the input changes. However, I am not having any luck as this is what I am seeing right now:

`input change detected  and undefined`

I don't know why search_input.val() and this.value are both null even though I can see clearly that I am typing something into the input.

Comment: use as `console.log('input change detected', $(this).val(), 'and');

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/r6tD4/

Comment: Should work fine, the `input` event catches any change, as in `key*` and `change` etc..

Answer (score 1):

Use [change method](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of input:

```
var search_input = $('#dynatable-search-');
  search_input.on('change', function() {
    console.log('input change detected', search_input.val(), 'and', this.value);
    dynatable.data('dynatable').queries.runSearch(search_input.val());
  });
```